# Using Google Cloud Datastore with NDB API?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, gcloud-python, google-cloud-python

There is a lot of info on using [NDB](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/) API with Google App Engine Datastore but I can't find any info on how to use NDB with Google Cloud Datastore. The only module I found is [googledatastore](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/googledatastore) which is very primitive library.

How is App Engine Datastore different from the Cloud Datastore? Is NDB available for the Cloud Datastore?

Comment: Per https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-datastore/issues/2 , the issue of using `ndb` to access the Google Cloud Datastore is an open one from Google's viepoint -- meanwhile many others are working on higher-abstraction-layer libraries on top of the low-level `googledatastore`, and you'll find plenty of links and discussions at that URL.

Answer (score 5):

NDB support outside of App Engine (using Google Cloud Datastore) is currently in development.

UPDATE: Check out the `NDB` development [discussion](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcloud-python/issues/557) on GitHub.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to try using `gcloud.datastore` (`pip install gcloud`).

Docs: http://googlecloudplatform.github.io/gcloud-python/

Code: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcloud-python